# Android : app running issue on Nougat OS

Tags: android, installation, android-7.0-nougat

I am working on an android app. Everything is working fine on marshmallow OS. But when i try to install app on Nougat OS then it is not allow me to install my app.

[image]

These is how my gradle file looks like :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.*****"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: Can you post the crash message trace?

Comment: "it is not allow me to install my app" -- that error dialog usually comes from running the app, not from installing the app. Beyond that, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I have run my app in android simulator having OS Nougat. It is working fine. But when i try to run it on actual device it is not working there.